# Remove ListB from ListA - Logic

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 List Objects, and need to remove all items from ListA that contains ListB and return the remaining. My approach is the following:

LIST A

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ant"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ant2"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "ant3"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "ant3"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "ant3"
}]
```

LIST B

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ant"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "ant4"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "ant3"
} ]
```

What I have tried:

```
const xxx = this.listA.filter(x => !listB.includes(x) != null);
```

Note (Alternative scenario): When there are 2 List that are identical, the expected result is a []. However, in my case its same as a single List.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are :)

```
const listBSerialized = listB.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)) 
const xxx = listA.filter(x => !listBSerialized.includes(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

You'll have the following result:

```
[ { id: 2, name: 'ant2' },
  { id: 4, name: 'ant3' },
  { id: 5, name: 'ant3' } ]
```

You can also use models ever you need properties order guarantee on the serialization, sometimes the objects can have the same properties but in a different order (it depends on where is the object coming from):

```
function Ant(id, name) {
  this.id = id
  this.name = name
}

listA = [
  new Ant(1, "ant"),
  new Ant(2, "ant2"),
  new Ant(3, "ant3"),
  new Ant(4, "ant3"),
  new Ant(5, "ant3")
]

listB = [
  new Ant(1, "ant"),
  new Ant(4, "ant4"),
  new Ant(3, "ant3")
]

const listBSerialized = listB.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)) 
const xxx = listA.filter(x => !listBSerialized.includes(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Comment: Never compare objects this way unless it really doesn't matter what result you want to get.

Comment: @MaciejKwas perhaps you could explain why this is inappropriate (e.g., key order is not guaranteed)?

Comment: @jcalz if these objects doesn't have the same hidden class (which is not guaranteed) then your keys order might be random, thus, if you would like to compare it this way you would have to split every object property to key/value array, sort, join and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one liner that will handle this task:

```
const xxx = listA.filter(base => ! listB.some(f => f.id === base.id && f.name === base.name))
```

where `a` is ListA and `b` is ListB array of objects. Basically what you would do is to filter the `a` array with a condition that there is no object that has the same id and name in `b` array.